# Image scaling in xamarin.forms, how to use unused space?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have following xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LayoutTest"
             x:Class="LayoutTest.MainPage">


    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="picture.png" BackgroundColor="Black" Scale="0.5"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Text="Text" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

which gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqizt.png)

Scaling image produces unused space between left edge of screen and image and between image and label cell. I expected when I set Width property value to Auto on first column and scaling image there would be no space to the left and right.

It looks like grid uses original image width when positioning elements.
Is this expected behavior?
How could I achieve expected behavior without using low res image?